# Error handling in SQL Server wrapper

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

For fun and to educate myself I'm writing my own SQL Server query wrapper for Powershell. Please see below where I'm currently at.

My main problem now is that if you call the Function with a wrong `username`, `password` or `servername`, it takes about a minute for PS to return a massive error. I would like to return more usefull error messages, ie.

- Login failed; user exists but wrong password
- Login failed; user does not exist
- Cannot find server
- etc..

Where and how in the current function could I implement the section for catching and parsing the PS error into usefull messages?

```
Function Query {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS 
        Query a SQL Server instance
    .EXAMPLE
        Query -query "SELECT column FROM table"
        This command returns a dataset from the SQL server.
    .DESCRIPTION
        This function returns different output based on the query type. DROP, 
        ALTER and DELETE statements are not allowed for security reasons.
    .LINK
        http://spark/publish-later
    #>

    param (
        [string]$query,
        [string]$server = "SQLEXPRESS",
        [string]$dbase  = "TEST",
        [string]$user,
        [string]$pass
    )

    if ($user) { 
        $connstr = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout=15" -f $server, $dbase, $user, $pass 
    } 
    else { # Windows Authentication is implied
        $connstr = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15" -f $server, $dbase
    }

    $conn  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connstr)

    try {
        $conn.Open()
        switch ($query.Split()[0]) {
            "SELECT" {
                $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$conn)
                $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
                $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                $adapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null
                return $dataset.Tables[0]
            }
            "UPDATE" {
                $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$conn)
                return $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            }
            "INSERT" {
                $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$conn)
                return $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            }
        }
        $conn.Close()
    }
    catch {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        return "$ex.Message"
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you should consider the first two, they're effectively security risks as they passively divulge information about user accounts.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate? AFAIK I need to build a connection string first, to connect to the database, no?

Comment: `Login failed; user exists but wrong password`, `Login failed; user does not exist` <--- Publishing these reasons is a security risk.

Comment: Ah yes. However, this tool is for internal use only. I'm trying to build a usefull library of functions that I might need every now and then...and in the mean time learn about PS. So putting security risks aside for now (I could also make the error message less instructive), could you get me started on getting some proper error handling in there?